# Need to Dynamically Change Headings in Fiori List Report Developed Using SAP Fiori Elements

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I do have a Fiori list report developed using SAP Fiori elements. I need to dynamically change the column headings.

I have a filter called "Period" which can be selected as "Monthly" or "Weekly". When the user has selected the "Monthly" option, the columns should have headings for next four months, like:

| 03/2023 | 04/2023 | 05/2023 | 06/2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

When the user has selected the "Weekly" option, the columns should have headings for next four periods, like:

| Calender 09 | Calender 10 | Calender 11 | Calender 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

How can I achieve the same, possibly with custom JS code in the front-end? Especially for the one which developed with Fiori elements.

Comment: Is the Fiori elements app based on OData V2? Or V4?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann . Is based on Odata V2

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this but something like this should work for your use case and if you are getting the column header data from your `oData` Service.

```js
// data for column headers can be read from OData call and stored in JSON Model
// OData call--
oLocalModel.setProperty("/MonthlyCols", oData.results[0].MonthlyCols);
oLocalModel.setProperty("/WeeklyCols", oData.results[0].WeeklyCols);


var oTable = this.getView().byId("TableId");
var aColumns = oTable.getColumns();
var oSelected = this.getView().byId("PeriodFilter").getSelectedKey();
if (oSelected == "Monthly") {
    for (var i = 0; i <= aColumns.length; i++) {
        //loop through monthly cols 
        var aMonthlyCols = oLocalModel.getData().MonthlyCols;
        for (var j = 0; j <= aMonthlyCols.length; j++) {
            aColumns[i].getLabel().setText(aMonthlyCols[j].key);
        }
    }
} else {
    for (var i = 0; i <= aColumns.length; i++) {
        //loop through weekly cols 
        var aWeeklyCols = oLocalModel.getData().WeeklyCols;
        for (var j = 0; j <= aWeeklyCols.length; j++) {
            aColumns[i].getLabel().setText(aWeeklyCols[j].key);
        }
    }
}
```